# Grease pencil 2.8 render doesn't work with pixel filter?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, grease-pencil

Hello I'm using the grease pencil to make some sprites for a video game but I found something very strange in this case. The pixel filter seems to not work in grease pencil objects.

I'm using the render eevee to have sharp edges on low resolution images.
I just have this quick scene the drawing is a grease pencil object the cube is a 3D object. Cube is the only thing that changes.

***I just change the Film->Filter Size 0.02*** 
This is my result. The Cube in violet looks pixelate that is my desired effect.

[image]

And this is what happens when ***I change the filter to 3.0 px***

[image]

As you can see the grease pencil is invulnerable to filter changes in the render. I know that I can just render a bigger version of my image and then using another software I can decrease the size with a nearest neighbor filter. But that would be a problem because I will animate my character that will increase work time.

In case you are confusing on what I'm doing this is my scene.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those are for general settings. The grease pencil settings (on viewport) and (on render) that you want to play along with, are right here:
[image]

Comment: That settings are very hidden. I hope the developers move this settings.

Answer (score 1):

## Blender 2.83

[image]

They added this settings for grease pencil, change the Anti-Aliasing Threshold and done.
This is more easy to do.

And Finally I can get my desired effect.

[image]